# Join two list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am learning prolog, what I am doing is writing a predicate to join two list. For example, if I query:

> `joinL([22,33,44],[1,2,3],L)`

It will show `L = [22,33,44,1,2,3]`.

To do it, I have tried to write predicate as followings:

```
joinL([],L2,L2).
joinL([H|T],L2,L):-joinL(T,L2,L),L = [H|L].
```

But when I query

> `joinL([22,33,44],[1,2,3],L)`

It does not show desired result as i have just described above. Actually, it returns `false`.

What I want to ask is: "How did my code become wrong?", I do NOT ask "How to write predicate that join two list in prolog?" cause I can google it easily, and when compare with my code, I curiously want to know why i am wrong with my code. Can any one help me! Thank you all for reading and answering my question!

Comment: If we want to approach your question with an open mind: your code is not wrong, it is simply not doing what you _want it to do_. In a similar vein of thought, if there exists code that does exactly what you need, it is usually "clever" to read that code and understand it. You can of course approach a programming language empirically, and study it experimentally, but I don't think that something as simple as a programming language deserves an experimental approach.

Comment: In a few words, you are re-discovering `append/3`.

Comment: @User9213 Thank you, Thank to your comments! I must practice more to understand this language, it's is strange with me.

Comment: I'd recommend the open access, free version of the book that you can find [on this website here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/art-prolog-second-edition) (look for the PDF download link). If you read it and solve the exercises you will get a good head-start in Prolog programming.

Comment: This intro is gentler: [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/). I remember "The Art of Prolog" fondly but it was tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `=` in the same way as one would use assignment:

```
L = [H|L]
```

In a state-changing language this means that whatever is stored in `L` (which is supposed to be a list) becomes a new list, made by tacking `H` to the front: `[H|L]`

In Prolog this states that what we know about `L` is that it is equal to `[H|L]`- equal to itself with `H` tacked to the front. This is not possible for any `L` though (actually, it is, if `L` is an infinite list containing only `H` but the proof engine of Prolog is not good enough to deal with *that*). Prolog's proof search fails at that hurdle and will return "false" - there are no solutions to the logic program you have entered.

(More after a coffee)

Here is how to think about this:

Ok, so I would like to state some logic facts about the problem of "list concatenation" so that, based on those logic facts, and given two completely-specified lists `L1`, `L2`, Prolog's proof search can determine enough about what the concatenated list `LJ` should look like to actually output it completely!

We decide to specify a predicate `joinL(list1,list2,joinedlist)` to express this.

First, we cover a special edge case:

```
joinL([],L2,LJ) :- LJ = L2.
```

So, it is stated that the 'joinL' relationship between the empty list '[]' and the joined list 'LJ' is such that 'LJ' is necessarily equal to 'L2'.

The *logical reading* is:

*(LJ = L2) → joinL([],L2,LJ)*

The *operational reading* is:

In order to prove `joinL([],L2,LJ)` you must prove `LJ = L2` (which can either be verified if `LJ` and `L2` are already known or can be added to the solution's known constraints if not.

There is also the reading of the SLD resolution, where you add the negation of `joinL([],L2,LJ)` to your set of logic facts, then try to prove ⊥ (the contradiction also know as the empty statement) using resolution, but I have not found that view to be particularly helpful.

Anyway, let's state more things about the edge cases:

```
joinL([],L2,LJ) :- LJ = L2.
joinL(L1,[],LJ) :- LJ = L1.
joinL([],[],LJ) :- LJ = [].
```

This will already enable the Prolog proof engine to determine `LJ` completely whenever any of the `L1` and `L2` is the empty list.

One commonly abbreviates to:

```
joinL([],L,L).
joinL(L,[],L).
joinL([],[],[]).
```

(The above abbreviation would not be possible in [Picat](http://picat-lang.org/) for example)

And the third statement can be dropped because the other two "subsume it" - they cover that case more generally. Thus:

```
joinL([],L,L).
joinL(L,[],L).
```

Now for the case of non-empty lists. A fat part of logic programming is about inductive (or recursive) definitions of predicates (see [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1880293_Logic_Programming_Functional_Programming_and_Inductive_Definitions)), so let's go:

```
joinL([H|T],L2,LJ) :- LJ = [H|LX], joinL(T,L2,LX).
```

Again, this is just a specification, where we say that the concatenation of a nonempty list `[H|T]` and any list `L2` is a list `LJ` such that `LJ` is composed of `H` and a list `LX` and `LX` is the concatenation of `T` and `L2`.

This is useful to the Prolog proof engine because it gives more information about `LJ` (in fact, it specifies what the first element of `LJ` is) and reduces the problem to finding out more using the same predicate but a problem that is a little nearer to the base case with the empty list: `joinL(T,L2,LX)`. If the proof goes down that route it will eventually hit `joinL([],L2,LX)`, find out that `L2 = LX` and be able to successfully return from its descent.

```
joinL([H|T],L2,LJ) :- LJ = [H|LX], joinL(T,L2,LX).
```

is commonly abbreviated to

```
joinL([H|T],L2,[H|LX]) :- joinL(T,L2,LX).
```

Looks like we have covered everything with:

```
joinL([],L,L).
joinL(L,[],L).
joinL([H|T],L2,[H|LX]) :- joinL(T,L2,LX).
```

We can even drop the second statement, as it is covered by the recursive descent with L2 always equal to '[]'. It gives us a shorter program which burns cycles needlessly when L2 is '[]':

```
joinL([],L,L).
joinL([H|T],L2,[H|LX]) :- joinL(T,L2,LX).
```

Let's test this. One should use [unit tests](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) but I can't be bothered now and will just run these in [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/). Let's see what Prolog can find out about `X`:

```
joinL([],[],X).       % X = []
joinL([1,2],[],X).    % X = [1,2] 
joinL([],[1,2],X).    % X = [1,2]
joinL([3,4],[1,2],X). % X = [3,4,1,2]
joinL([1,2],[3,4],X). % X = [1,2,3,4]
```

One can constrain the result completely, transforming Prolog into a checker:

```
joinL([3,4],[1,2],[3,4,1,2]). % true
joinL([3,4],[1,2],[1,1,1,1]). % false
```

Sometimes the predicate works backwards too, but often more careful design is needed. Not here:

```
joinL([3,4],L2,[3,4,1,2]). % L2 = [1, 2]
```

For this one, Prolog suggests a second solution *might* exist but there is none of course:

```
joinL(L1,[3,4],[1,2,3,4]). % L1 = [1, 2]
```

Find me something impossible:

```
joinL(L1,[3,4],[1,2,100,100]). % false
```

Comment: But, why I still get wrong when replace `=` by `is` operator? Does the `is` not used to assign list in prolog?

Comment: @TaQuangTu `=` and `is` are totally different. `=` is _unification_, `is` _evaluates an arithmetic expression_ like `1+2`. You should be able to read about that in a textbook.

Comment: @TaQuangTu I suppose you were hoping that `is` was some kind of destructive assignment unlike `=` which is unification. There is no destructive assignment in Prolog. Now would be a good time to start reading. Prolog really is not the kind of language you can just bang away at. It is fundamentally and thoroughly different than any other language you have used and you will have to read and think about it to make sense of it.